# How to use the Ember.Select value to filter JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I want to filter my JSON using Ember.Select value instead of hardcoding it. Here's my App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function(controller) {
        this.render('MyApp', {
            controller : controller
        });
    },
    model : function() {
        return App.MyTemplateModel.find();
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    filteredContent : Ember.computed.oneWay("content"),
    last : function() {
        var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('last_name', "Solow");
        this.set("filteredContent", filtered);

    }
});

App.MyTemplateModel = Ember.Model.extend({
    id : Ember.attr(),
    last_name : Ember.attr(),
    first_name : Ember.attr(),
    suffix : Ember.attr(),
    expiration : Ember.attr()
});

App.controller = Ember.Object.create({
    selectedProgrammer : null,
    content : [Ember.Object.create({
        last_name : "Solow",
        id : 1
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        last_name : "Tom",
        id : 2
    })]
});

App.MyTemplateModel.url = "http://ankur1.local/index.php/api/example/users/";
App.MyTemplateModel.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();
var existing = App.MyTemplateModel.find();
App.MyTemplateModel.camelizeKeys = true;
```

In the line,

```
 var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('last_name', "Solow");
```

I am harcoding "Solow" but I want to use Ember.Select value.

I tried doing this,

```
 var selectedProgrammer = App.controller.get("selectedProgrammer");
 var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('lastName', App.controller.get('selectedProgrammer'));
 this.set("filteredContent", filtered);
```

But it does nothing & moreover, here's what I am doing on HTML,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyApp">
{{#each item in filteredContent }}
            <tr><td>
            {{id}} <p> {{item.first_name}} {{item.expiration}}</p>
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

            <button {{action last}}>filter</button>

            {{view Ember.Select
            contentBinding="App.controller.content"
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            optionLabelPath="content.last_name"
            selectionBinding="App.controller.selectedProgrammer"}}
</script>
```

Furthermore, here's a sample of JSON, http://pastebin.com/7dyNQi4K

Where I might be wrong or What changes I might have to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Ember.Select` is bound to `App.controller.selectedProgrammer`, when the select changes, it will receive an object. So in your controller you access the `last_name` property from that object using `App.controller.get('selectedProgrammer.last_name')`.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    filteredContent : Ember.computed.oneWay("content"),
    last : function() {
        var lastName = App.controller.get('selectedProgrammer.last_name');
        var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('last_name', lastName);
        this.set("filteredContent", filtered);
    }
});
```